# why notifySetDataChanged did not work in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I make demo in which I show data from webservice .Which is working fine .Mean I am able to display data on listview when I hit service first time.But I need hit server again and again and get new data .I am able to get new data .but I need to show new data on listview but my list become blank or empty when I got new data . why ?

here is my code .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.departure_dashboard);

    try {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("Response");
        Log.d("=========onCreate", message);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         data = new Gson().fromJson(message, deparaturedaseboarddto.class);
         listObject=data.getData();
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,  listObject);

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         timer =new Timer();
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new alertTask(), 0, 14000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

when Timer start I used alerk task.and call webservice again and again

```
public class alertTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WebserviceMethod callDepartudeDashboard=new WebserviceMethod();
            callDepartudeDashboard.setObserver(Departuredashboardscreen.this);
            callDepartudeDashboard.getwebService(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"departuredashboard"+"?crsCode=hnh");


        }

    }
```

It is the method which give response again and again ...

```
@Override
    public void getWebserviceResponse(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("timer", result);
        listObject.clear();


         deparaturedaseboarddto localdata = new Gson().fromJson(result, deparaturedaseboarddto.class);
         listObject.addAll(localdata.getData());
        adapter.notifySetDataChanged();

    }
```

here is my custom adapter for listview

```
package com.firstgroup.components;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload;
import com.firstgroup.applicationload.R;
import com.firstgroup.dto.deparaturedaseboarddto;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto;
    private Context context;
    public CustomListAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<deparaturedaseboarddto> deparaturedaseboarddto){
        this.deparaturedaseboarddto=deparaturedaseboarddto;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listitem, null);
            }

            final TextView platFormName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_platform);

            final TextView schDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_schDepart);
            final TextView expDepart = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expectdepart);
            final TextView arrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_arrival);
            final TextView exparrival = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_expertarrival);
            final TextView stationName = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_stationName);

            final String platformValue = deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getPlatformNo();
            final String schDepartValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getSchDepart();
            final String schExpectValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getExpDepart();
            final String arrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
            final String exparrivalValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestSchArrival();
           String stationNameValue= deparaturedaseboarddto.get(position).getDestinationStation().getStationName();

            platFormName.setText(platformValue);

            schDepart.setText(schDepartValue);
            expDepart.setText(schExpectValue);
            arrival.setText(arrivalValue);
            exparrival.setText(exparrivalValue);
            stationName.setText(stationNameValue);
            return v;
    }

    public void notifySetDataChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

}
```

When I press back it show the new list for a second than close the application why ?

Comment: It won't work unless you register a `DataSetObserver` to the adapter.

Comment: how i will register ?

Comment: The easiest way for you is probably to call `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` again right after `listObject.addAll(localdata.getData());`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have written your `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside  BaseAdapter, while it should be ideally called after you set the adapter to your list view.
or it might also be because inside the base adapter you have a method

```
public void notifySetDataChanged() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

but you are not calling your `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the method with a instance of array adapter.
Please refer this [tutorial](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/)

Comment: start by commenting out the notifySetDataChanged() method in your base adapter and add this line of code  adapter.notifySetDataChanged(); after listView.setAdapter(adapter);. Please look at the link i gave you it explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the adapter by assigning it the complete list view like list view.set adapter() with new data. Sorry for my bad indentation